# Sailsjs 404 (Not Found) api rest delete

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, sails.js

**HTML**

When i try to delete some data i get this in my console :When i try to delete some data i get this in my console :When i try to delete some data i get this in my console :When i try to delete some data i get this in my console :

```
 DELETE https://sails-backoffice.herokuapp.com/api/todo/:id 404 (Not Found)
```

any idea ?

```
<tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="todo in listTodo">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{todo.id}}</td>
            <td>{{todo.titre}}</td>
            <td ng-class="{'completed': todo.completed == true}"><a href="/message-details/{{todo.id}}">{{todo.message}}</a></td>
            <!--<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button></td>-->
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(todo.id)">Supprimer</button></td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('crud')
  .controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope,$routeParams,Todolist,$http,Todo) {
      $scope.delete=function(id){

                var removed=Todo.removeTodo(id);

            removed.success(function (data, status, headers, jwr) {

                  $scope.listTodo=data;


          })
          .error(function (data, status, headers, jwr) {



              console.log(data);

          });

          };  });
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('crud')
  .service('Todo', function ($http) {
 removeTodo:function(id){

            return $http.delete('https://sails-backoffice.herokuapp.com/api/todo/:id',id);
        },

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using blueprint api's then try this by removing 'api'

```
return $http.delete('https://sails-backoffice.herokuapp.com/todo/:id',id);
```

else
you need to define route in config/route.js

Answer (score 0):

DELETE is an HTTP verb, meaning you're sending an AJAX request with JQuery  to your /api/todo/:id route. If you haven't configured sails.js' `config/routes` file with that route, it'll send back this 404.

I recommend reading through the [sails documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes) about routes.